# How to install LWJGL3 in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, lwjgl, libraries, game-development

I want to write a little project for which I have chosen LWJGL library.
But I have some problem with installing it into Visual Studio Code IDE. I have found manuals for Eclipse, NetBeans, and IntelliJ, but none for the VSC. Can you please write a detailized guide how to install LWJGL3 into VSC? 
Please write what and where I should copy files and where to add them into dependencies for my project.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you stick with [Maven](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/index.html) which is a java widely used dependency manager. It will allow you to build your project independently of any IDE.

So an LWJGL can be build via Maven. Just go to [customize](https://www.lwjgl.org/customize) section, select what you need and it will show you below how to add LWJGL to Maven.

But also spend some time to know Maven a little. It will help you a lot.

Comment: Btw this is my LWJGL game built with Maven. You can refer to it as an example https://github.com/aunmag/shooter

Comment: Ok, I downloaded pom.xml, added everything from there to the pom.xml of my project. How to make maven to download those dependencies to my computer?

Comment: Have you installed maven first?

Comment: Using terminal `cd` into your project directory and then run `mvn compile` command, it will download all the dependencies and compile your project.